# Retrieving data from next/router and local storage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to create a social media app as a project. I have two pages: `posts.js` and `[id].js`.

posts.js

```
<div
  className={styles.userDetails}
  onClick={() => { 
    router.push({ pathname : `/user/${props.user._id}`})
  }}
>
</div>
```

When user clicks on this `div`, user will be redirected to `[id].js`. In this case, `id` retrieved from router is used as `userId`. But when user want to view his own profile, `usedId` should be retrieved from localStorage. When the user logs in, user's id will be saved to localStorage.

```js
const [userId, setUserId] = useState()

const getUserData = async () => {
  try {
    if (router.query.id != undefined ) {
      setUserId(router.query.id)
    } else {
      setUserId(getUser())
    }
    const res = await instance.get(`/user/${userId}`)
    setUser(res.data)
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

useEffect(() => {
  getUserData()
  getPosts()
}, [router.query])
```

I tried to set `userId` using if condition. But at the time of loading the page, value of `router.query.id` is undefined. It takes a bit to retrieve the id from router. Due to this I get `userId` = undefined.

I have made a condition like `if (router.push.id != "undefined"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When the user views his own profile, you still redirect the same way, right, with the `/user/${props.user._id}`?

Comment: I have created the link to profile from navigation bar. There i have used <Link> to redirect to [id].js. Let me replace is with router push method

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is: on the detail page, if the user is viewing their own profile, there will not be an id in the URL, right?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time sir. Now I have got solution for my problems. When user click view profile, router push method is used instead of <Link>